# STM32 hits breakpoint when TIM1 prescaler > 2

Tags: stm32f10x

I'm generating a PWM signal on STM32F103 using TIM1. Timebase init code is:

```
timebase_prescale = 1;
timebase_reload = 3000;


TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timebase;
timebase.TIM_Prescaler = timebase_prescale - 1;
timebase.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
timebase.TIM_Period = timebase_reload;
timebase.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
timebase.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &timebase);

TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM1, ENABLE);
```

With some additional code to configure channel 1 and an I/O pin I get a 24 kHz output signal. Perfect.

When setting

```
timebase_prescale = 2;
```

I get 12 kHz instead as expected - but as soon as I use anything > 2 the processor stops and OpenOCD reports

```
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread
```

What's going wrong?

**EDIT:**

After the above timebase config, pins are initialized and the PWM is started:

```
void multipwm_setup_channel(int channel)
{
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef config;

    config.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;  // or 2 ???
    config.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    config.TIM_OutputNState = TIM_OutputNState_Enable;
    config.TIM_Pulse = timebase_reload / 4;  // initial compare value

    config.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    config.TIM_OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPolarity_High;

    config.TIM_OCIdleState = TIM_OCIdleState_Reset;
    config.TIM_OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIdleState_Reset;

    switch (channel)
    {
        case 1:
            gpio_config(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_8, GPIO_Mode_AF_PP, GPIO_Speed_10MHz);
            gpio_config(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_13, GPIO_Mode_AF_PP, GPIO_Speed_10MHz);
            TIM_OC1Init(TIM1, &config);
            TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM1, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
            break;

        case 2:
            gpio_config(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_9, GPIO_Mode_AF_PP, GPIO_Speed_10MHz);
            gpio_config(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_14, GPIO_Mode_AF_PP, GPIO_Speed_10MHz);
            TIM_OC2Init(TIM1, &config);
            break;

....

    }
}
```

The complete init sequence is

```
    multipwm_setup();  // enables timer 1 clock
    multipwm_set_frequency(30000);
    multipwm_setup_channel(1);
    multipwm_setup_channel(2);
    multipwm_start();  // calls TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE);
```

Clock runs at 72MHz; configuration as default from some standard system startup code I didn't write myself. The 30000 Hz are what I actually wanted (calculates timebase_prescale as 1), but I tried 50 Hz just to see if my code would work and found that it failed with higher prescale values.

---

`TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs()` needs to be called before `TIM_TimeBaseInit()`. Now I can use whatever prescaler value I need.

But still did not always work! Adding `TIM_Cmd(TIM1, DISABLE);` and re-enabling the timer later seems to solve the problem - for now?

Comment: Can you add your pwm configuration? Basically, you can use timer_output_compare mode for PWM generation. How to use the driver is defined in Std_Peripheral library and the function TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(..) is used for special timer features. If you can post your complete complete pwm & clock configuration, it would be good!

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem that I can see, without going into any calculation is with this line

```
 TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM1, ENABLE);
```

As I have mentioned in the comment, you do not need that! Do you know this particular function according to Std_Peripheral_Library enables MOE(Main Output) in BDTR(Break & Dead time register)? and If it is your intention to use it, you need to configure it accordingly!

What you are essentially doing is turning the timer on for a special purpose and reconfiguring it for PWM and turning the timer counter on(TIM_Cmd function) again! I think this is causing the conflict. The solution is to simply remove the above line from your code.

I am not sure what your "multipwm_set_frequency" function does! But it is in general very easy to configure the timer for desired PWM frequency.

Desired PWM frequency = (TIM_CLK/PrescalerValue-1)/(Period-1);

It is in general accurate to calculate PrescalerValue from system_core_clock value. You can then use, pulse value as Period/4 for 25% duty cycle(as you have done), Period/2 for 50% duty cycle and so on...

Comment: Without that line the code always crashes. This is specific for Timer 1 and has been mentioned in many other posts.

Comment: Hey, can you explain why does it crash? The driver does not mention anything about using TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs function for normal PWM output. It is needed only if you use some break feature. You must be doing something wrong!

Comment: It does not make sense but have you tried putting the TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs line after the complete timer configuration i.e after multipwm_start(); line. If you have to use it, use it after complete timer configuration, enabling the counter first and then enabling the break feature.

Comment: Similar problem is mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728281/error-using-tim1-for-pwm-on-stm32f0)

Comment: Correction: you're right, it did not crash, it just didn't output anything. Same problem as with the post you mentioned. Obviously Output Control needs to be set for TIM1 being an "Advanced Timer", but when exactly is not perfectly clear.  -- I'll leave it at that (for the moment), since I found a somehow working version and my final hardware will probably not use deadtime or TIM1 any more.

Comment: It should work if you keep it after multipwm_start(); line, there are several example codes uses that way.